# How to make button disable if textarea is empty

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a textarea like below, when the value is empty then the "*convert*" and "*clear value*" buttons are not active/disable, they will be active only if the textarea field has a value.

If the value is cleared manually it has worked properly, but the problem is if the "*clear value*" function works to empty the text area value the button is still active.

how to fix that when the textarea field is emptied by the "*clear value*" function, the two buttons become inactive.
so they are only active when the textarea field contains a value.

```js
let $btn = document.querySelector('#convert')
$btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  let inputArr = document.querySelector('#inputTextarea').value.split('\n');
  let $result = document.querySelector('#outputTextarea')
  let number = 1
  let final = []

  for (row of inputArr) {
    let rowArr = row.split(' | ')
    let first = rowArr.shift().split(':')
    let nrString = `+No.` + number
    let mail = `Email: ${first[0]}`
    let token = `Token: ${first[1]}`

    rowArr.unshift(nrString, mail, token);
    rowArr = rowArr.join('\n')
    final.push(rowArr)
    number++
  }

  let finalText = final.join('\n\n')
  $result.value = finalText
});

//button copy result
let buttonCopy = document.getElementById("copyResult"),
  input = document.getElementById("outputTextarea");

buttonCopy.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  input.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  //alert("Result copied");
});

//Clear input textarea value
const inputTextarea = document.getElementById("inputTextarea");
const btnClear = document.getElementById('clearValue');
btnClear.addEventListener('click', function handleClick() {
  inputTextarea.value = '';
});

//disable action button if textarea empty
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.inputTextarea textarea').keyup(function() {

    var empty = false;
    $('.inputTextarea textarea').each(function() {
      if ($(this).val().length == 0) {
        empty = true;
      }
    });

    if (empty) {
      $('.actionTextarea button').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    } else {
      $('.actionTextarea button').attr('disabled', false);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.0/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<div class="container m-4">
  <div class="form-group inputTextarea">
    <label for="inputTextarea">Paste bulk text bellow</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" id="inputTextarea" rows="3"></textarea>
  </div>

  <!-- Button trigger modal -->
  <div class="actionTextarea">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalTextarea" id="convert" disabled>
Convert
</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" id="clearValue" disabled>Clear value</button>
  </div>
</div>

<!--Result area-->
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modalTextarea" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Convert result</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
<span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
</button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <textarea class="form-control" id="outputTextarea" rows="8"></textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="copyResult">Copy Result</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just disable the input after you click clear text button.

```js
let $btn = document.querySelector('#convert')
$btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  let inputArr = document.querySelector('#inputTextarea').value.split('\n');
  let $result = document.querySelector('#outputTextarea')
  let number = 1
  let final = []

  for (row of inputArr) {
    let rowArr = row.split(' | ')
    let first = rowArr.shift().split(':')
    let nrString = `+No.` + number
    let mail = `Email: ${first[0]}`
    let token = `Token: ${first[1]}`

    rowArr.unshift(nrString, mail, token);
    rowArr = rowArr.join('\n')
    final.push(rowArr)
    number++
  }

  let finalText = final.join('\n\n')
  $result.value = finalText
});

//button copy result
let buttonCopy = document.getElementById("copyResult"),
  input = document.getElementById("outputTextarea");

buttonCopy.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  input.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  //alert("Result copied");
});

//Clear input textarea value
const inputTextarea = document.getElementById("inputTextarea");
const btnClear = document.getElementById('clearValue');
btnClear.addEventListener('click', function handleClick() {
  inputTextarea.value = '';
  $('.actionTextarea button').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});

//disable action button if textarea empty
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.inputTextarea textarea').keyup(function() {

    var empty = false;
    $('.inputTextarea textarea').each(function() {
      if ($(this).val().length == 0) {
        empty = true;
      }
    });

    if (empty) {
      $('.actionTextarea button').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    } else {
      $('.actionTextarea button').attr('disabled', false);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.0/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<div class="container m-4">
  <div class="form-group inputTextarea">
    <label for="inputTextarea">Paste bulk text bellow</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" id="inputTextarea" rows="3"></textarea>
  </div>

  <!-- Button trigger modal -->
  <div class="actionTextarea">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalTextarea" id="convert" disabled>
Convert
</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" id="clearValue" disabled>Clear value</button>
  </div>
</div>

<!--Result area-->
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modalTextarea" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Convert result</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
<span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
</button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <textarea class="form-control" id="outputTextarea" rows="8"></textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="copyResult">Copy Result</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @Mina, for the umpteenth time you solved my problem

Answer (score 3):

Plain old html and CSS using required and invalid selector

```css
form:invalid button {
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0.3;
}
```

```html
<form>
<textarea required></textarea>
<button>click</button>
<button>click</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would make a function called something like "updateButtons", and whenever it is called, it just checks to see if the text area has text or not, and then enables or disables the buttons appropriately.  Then you can call that function from the text area's onchange, onmouseup, keyup, and so on.  And you can also call it at the end of the function that clears the text area.  So, when the button is pressed, it clears the text area and then just calls for the code to see what state the buttons should be in.

Answer (score 1):

Not an elegant solution but this does work.

```js
let $btn = document.querySelector('#convert')
$btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  let inputArr = document.querySelector('#inputTextarea').value.split('\n');
  let $result = document.querySelector('#outputTextarea')
  let number = 1
  let final = []

  for (row of inputArr) {
    let rowArr = row.split(' | ')
    let first = rowArr.shift().split(':')
    let nrString = `+No.` + number
    let mail = `Email: ${first[0]}`
    let token = `Token: ${first[1]}`

    rowArr.unshift(nrString, mail, token);
    rowArr = rowArr.join('\n')
    final.push(rowArr)
    number++
  }

  let finalText = final.join('\n\n')
  $result.value = finalText
});

//button copy result
let buttonCopy = document.getElementById("copyResult"),
  input = document.getElementById("outputTextarea");

buttonCopy.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  input.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  //alert("Result copied");
});

//Clear input textarea value
const inputTextarea = document.getElementById("inputTextarea");
const btnClear = document.getElementById('clearValue');
btnClear.addEventListener('click', function handleClick() {
  inputTextarea.value = '';
   $('.actionTextarea button').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});

//disable action button if textarea empty
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.inputTextarea textarea').keyup(function() {

    var empty = false;
    $('.inputTextarea textarea').each(function() {
      if ($(this).val().length == 0) {
        empty = true;
      }
    });

    if (empty) {
      $('.actionTextarea button').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    } else {
      $('.actionTextarea button').attr('disabled', false);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.0/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<div class="container m-4">
  <div class="form-group inputTextarea">
    <label for="inputTextarea">Paste bulk text bellow</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" id="inputTextarea" rows="3"></textarea>
  </div>

  <!-- Button trigger modal -->
  <div class="actionTextarea">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalTextarea" id="convert" disabled>
Convert
</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" id="clearValue" disabled>Clear value</button>
  </div>
</div>

<!--Result area-->
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modalTextarea" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Convert result</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
<span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
</button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <textarea class="form-control" id="outputTextarea" rows="8"></textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="copyResult">Copy Result</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Ashen, i have tried the code you added and it works very well

Answer (score 1):

Its work fine now

```js
let $btn = document.querySelector('#convert')
$btn.addEventListener('click', function () {
let inputArr = document.querySelector('#inputTextarea').value.split('\n');
let $result = document.querySelector('#outputTextarea')
let number = 1
let final = []

for (row of inputArr) {
let rowArr = row.split(' | ')
let first = rowArr.shift().split(':')
let nrString = `+No.` + number
let mail = `Email: ${first[0]}`
let token = `Token: ${first[1]}`

rowArr.unshift(nrString, mail, token);
rowArr = rowArr.join('\n')
final.push(rowArr)
number++
}

let finalText = final.join('\n\n')
$result.value = finalText
});

//button copy result
let buttonCopy = document.getElementById("copyResult"),
input = document.getElementById("outputTextarea");

buttonCopy.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
event.preventDefault();
input.select();
document.execCommand("copy");
//alert("Result copied");
});

//Clear input textarea value
const inputTextarea = document.getElementById("inputTextarea");
const btnClear = document.getElementById('clearValue');
btnClear.addEventListener('click', function handleClick() {
inputTextarea.value = '';
$btn.disabled = true;
});

//disable action button if textarea empty
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.inputTextarea textarea').keyup(function() {

var empty = false;
$('.inputTextarea textarea').each(function() {
if ($(this).val().length == 0) {
empty = true;
}
});

if (empty) {
$('.actionTextarea button').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
} else {
$('.actionTextarea button').attr('disabled', false);
}
});
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.0/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<div class="container m-4">
<div class="form-group inputTextarea">
<label for="inputTextarea">Paste bulk text bellow</label>
<textarea class="form-control" id="inputTextarea" rows="3"></textarea>
</div>

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<div class="actionTextarea">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalTextarea"
id="convert" disabled>
Convert
</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" id="clearValue" disabled>Clear value</button>
</div>
</div>

<!--Result area-->
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modalTextarea" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
aria-labelledby="modalTitle" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
<h5 class="modal-title">Convert result</h5>
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
<span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
</button>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
<textarea class="form-control" id="outputTextarea" rows="8"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="copyResult">Copy Result</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @Muhammad Naeem, Thanks, simple solution but somehow I missed it.

Answer (score 1):

You can always simply have a single function that is called both on input of the textareas but also in the click handler for your clear button.

You have a bunch of code that isn't needed for the question, so I just have the following working code.

```js
function validateTextareas() {
  var empty = false;

  $('.inputTextarea textarea').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val().length == 0) {
      empty = true;
    }
  });
  
    $('.actionTextarea button').attr('disabled', empty);
}

$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.inputTextarea textarea').on("input", function() {
    validateTextareas();
  });

  $(".btn-clear").on("click", function() {
    $(".inputTextarea textarea").val("");
    validateTextareas();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="inputTextarea">
  <textarea>aaaa</textarea>
</div>

<div class="actionTextarea">
  <button class="btn-clear">Clear</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @Invaim2 Thanks for your answer, I have proved and it works great